# Mapping analyser for splitting string in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

is it possible to create a mapping analyser for splitting string into smaller parts based on count of characters?

For example, let's say I have a string: "ABCD1E2F34". This is some token constructed from multiple smaller codes and I want to break it down to those codes again.

If I know for sure that:
- First code is always 4 letters ("ABCD")
- Second is 3 letters ("1E2")
- Third is 1 letter ("F")
- Fourth is 2 letters ("34")

Can I create a mapping analyser for a field that will map the string like this? If I set the field "bigCode" to have value "ABCD1E2F34" I will be able to access it like this:

```
bigCode.full ("ABCD1E2F34")
bigCode.first ("ABCD")
bigCode.second ("1E2")
...
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about Pattern tokenizer? I create a regex to split string to tokens which is `(?<=(^\\w{4}))|(?<=^\\w{4}(\\w{3}))|(?<=^\\w{4}\\w{3}(\\w{1}))|(?<=^\\w{4}\\w{3}\\w{1}(\\w{2}))`. After that I created an analyzer like that:

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "codeanalyzer": {
              "type": "pattern",
              "pattern":"(?<=(^\\w{4}))|(?<=^\\w{4}(\\w{3}))|(?<=^\\w{4}\\w{3}(\\w{1}))|(?<=^\\w{4}\\w{3}\\w{1}(\\w{2}))"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

POST /myindex/_analyze?analyzer=codeanalyzer&text=ABCD1E2F34
```

And the result is tokenized data:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "abcd",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "1e2",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "f",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "34",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

You can check the documentation also : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html